# How to filter only site specific users in "Users and Organizations" in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

Currently all the members created in liferay are displays to all.
How I can filter out the users based on the sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Organization for distributed user management. Follow below step to achieve your requirement.

1. Add Organization
2. Goto your Site->Membership->Organization and select the organization you added
3. Add the user in the organization you want to give access for user management for the selected site and assign organization administration.
4. Login with the organization administration and you will see only site specific users.

hope this will help you.